# soft keyboard: keep one view stationary while moving other

Tags: android

I have a project in which I want one view to stay where it is when the soft keyboard shows, while a different view automatically scrolls with the soft keyboard.  Alternatively, neither views would automatically scroll but I would be able to manually scroll the second view to the correct position (most importantly, there would be one view at the top that is stationary).

Can anyone offer advice?

Comment: The second part is easy: you can e.g. use a ScrollView to contain the second view, while the top view will be a fixed layout. Like vertical LinearLayout containing a TextView and a ScrollView, for example. But the first part of the question is really interesting. I've seen that in some apps, and i like it. For example to keep Save and Cancel buttons always visible, whether the keyboard is shown or not.

Comment: I'm actually using a LinearLayout with a TextView at top and a subclass of a TextView on the bottom.  Only the second (custom, bottom) TextView is ever focusable and only it handles the input connection.  This is why I don't know why it is moving the top TextView (I want that one to always be visible).